# Create a TYPE in Oracle PL/SQL as "mirror" of existing table

Tags: oracle, types, plsql

Assume I have a table in my database called

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEES ( id number, lname varchar2(10))
```

I know I can create a user defined TYPE as follows

```
create type t_EMP authid definer as object ( id number, lname varchar2(30))
```

But is there a way to DYNAMICALLY create type without having to specify all column names ( so that next time the table changes, all I have to do is drop/recreate the TYPE)

Comment: Your title and tags refer to PL/SQL - where you can use `%rowtype` instead of creating a new type. But you've shown a SQL `create type` to create an object. What are you actually trying to do? You can create a schema-level type with dynamic SQL (in PL/SQL) via the data dictionary, but that seems like overkill. If you're changing a table definition - hopefully under source control - changing the object definition at the same time doesn't seem like a problem.

Comment: @Alex - taking a clue from your response, I was able to do the following: declare TYPE t_tab is table of EMPLOYEE%ROWTYPES.  I am trying to write a procedure to which a table name will be passed. The procedure will then fill that table up with dummy test records.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create type

You can just create variable using your table like this

```
variable_name table_name%rowtype;
```

Then you can use it as you want

```
variable_name.id := 5;
variable_name.lname := 'some name';
```